# Signal connections in a separate class

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, refactoring, signals-slots

I have some problems with refactoring of my code. Here is my small example:

```
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        but1 = QtGui.QPushButton("OK1")

        myUtils = ButtinUtils()
        but2 = myUtils.createButton(self.sender())

        hbox = QtGui.QFormLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(but1)
        hbox.addWidget(but2)

        self.setLayout(hbox)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Buttons')
        self.show()

        but1.clicked.connect(self.foo1)

    def foo1(self):
        print "foo1 called"

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The ideas is to create my second button in a own class. I can display the button on my main window, but how can I get a **connection**?

Here is the second class:

```
class ButtinUtils(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.createButton()
        #b1 = QtGui.QPushButton("OK")

    def createButton(self):
         but2 = QtGui.QPushButton("OK2")
         return but2
```

It would be great to outsource the event handler also to this util class.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have a reference to `but2` in your main class already, just connect to it the same way you do `but1`.

Comment: Hi! What exactly do you mean? I tried: but2.clicked.connect(myUtils.foo2) but that is not working (foo2 is in the Utils class)

Comment: That's because the `myUtils` object is garbage-collected as soon as the `initUi` method has finished. You need to make `myUtils` a member and then connect to it with: but2.clicked.connect(**self**.myUtils.foo2)